# Simple injector - decorators causing container to not be garbage collected?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I've noticed that when I add decorator(s) via simple injector, that the container won't go out of scope.  Does anyone know if this is expected? If I don't add the decorators, the container is Garbage collected. Otherwise, it's not. Is there anything I should be doing to force cleanup?

Here is a simple example.  If the decorators are added, the containers are still in memory after 'Run' has completed. If the decorators are not added, the containers get GC'ed.

```
public interface IDoSomething { }
public class DoSomething: IDoSomething { }
public class DoSomethingDec1: IDoSomething {
    public DoSomethingDec1(IDoSomething handler) { }
}
public class DoSomethingDec2 : IDoSomething {
    public DoSomethingDec2(IDoSomething handler) { }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Press a key to start");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
    Run();
    GC.Collect();
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}

static void Run() {
    //can be re-created with 1 container; easier to see with multiple
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        using (var container = new Container()) {
            container.Register<IDoSomething, DoSomething>();

            //Comment out these 2 lines to remove the decorators
            container.RegisterDecorator<IDoSomething, DoSomethingDec1>();
            container.RegisterDecorator<IDoSomething, DoSomethingDec2>();

            container.Verify();

            container.GetInstance<IDoSomething>();
        }
    }
}
```

With decorators:

[image]

Without decorators:

[image]

Comment: Why are you creating multiple container instances? The documentation [advices](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html) to create a single container instances and warns to *not* create an 'infinite number of container instances'.

Comment: Hi Steven,  The example creates multiple to make it easier to spot.  However, this happens with just a single container.  I'm creating a library that uses simple injector internally (single container) - i can't be sure when the user will dispose of my root object (which contains the SI container).    That's how i noticed that the container doesn't release.

Comment: It seems we got ourselves a memory leak. I am able to reproduce this. It's yet unclear to me why those instances are kept alive, but rest assure that this isn't intentional, is a bug, we will find the reason and we will fix this.

Comment: But that said, using a DI container within your library might not be the best choice. Read [this excellent post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/) from Mark Seemann about DI friendly libraries.

Comment: Thanks Steven.  I'll check out the post you linked. If it makes any difference, my usage of simple injector is an implementation detail. The library itself gives no direct indication that SI is being used - the user never interacts with it directly.

Comment: This issue has been reported in [github issue #135](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/135) and an analysis has been done (and posted) that describes what causes this memory leak.

Comment: The source of the problem is [a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172615/memory-leak-when-threadlocalt-is-used-in-cyclic-graph) in the .NET framework. We will publish a patch release that will work around the issue.

Comment: This bug has been fixed in [v3.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector/3.1.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This issue is fixed in [v3.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector/3.1.1).

The problem is caused by a [bug in the .NET framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172615/memory-leak-when-threadlocalt-is-used-in-cyclic-graph) that keeps cyclic object graphs alive if the graph contains a `ThreadLocal<T>`. In the case of Simple Injector, the decorator subsystem adds a `ThreadLocal<T>` to the `Container`'s `Items` dictionary. The `ThreadLocal`'s value indirectly references the `Container` again, causing the graph to become cyclic. Due to the bug in .NET, the `ThreadLocal<T>` is thought to be alive, keeping its depending object, such as the `Container` alive. The `Container` instance again keeps everything else alive, which obviously causes a memory leak.

Although we could wait for Microsoft to fix this, this will likely take way too long. So our plan is to address this issue in a future patch release. We will likely replace .NET's `ThreadLocal<T>` with our own custom implementation that doesn't cause the memory leak. This custom implementation is already used in Simple Injector's PCL library, since `ThreadLocal<T>` is not available for PCL. This implies that the PCL version of Simple Injector does not have this problem.