# Memory leak when ThreadLocal<T> is used in cyclic graph

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, .net-4.5

I just came across this weird 'behavior' of the Garbage Collector concerning `System.Threading.ThreadLocal<T>` that I can't explain. In normal circumstances, `ThreadLocal<T>` instances will be garbage collected when they go out of scope, even if they aren't disposed properly, except in the situation where they are part of a cyclic object graph.

The following example demonstrates the problem:

```
public class Program
{
    public class B { public A A; }
    public class A { public ThreadLocal<B> LocalB; }

    private static List<WeakReference> references = new List<WeakReference>();

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            CreateGraph();

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        // Expecting to print 0, but it prints 1000
        Console.WriteLine(references.Count(c => c.IsAlive));
    }

    static void CreateGraph() {
        var a = new A { LocalB = new ThreadLocal<B>() };
        a.LocalB.Value = new B { A = a };
        references.Add(new WeakReference(a));

        // If either one of the following lines is uncommented, the cyclic
        // graph is broken, and the programs output will become 0.
        // a.LocalB = null;
        // a.LocalB.Value = null;
        // a.LocalB.Value.A = null;
        // a.LocalB.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Although not calling `Dispose` is not good practice, but it's the CLR's design to clean up resources (by calling the finalizer) eventually, even if `Dispose` is not called.

Why does `ThreadLocal` behave differently in this regard and can cause memory leaks when not disposed properly in case of a cyclic graph? Is this by design? And if so, where is this documented? Or is this a bug in the CLR's GC?

(Tested under .NET 4.5).

Comment: [David Kean](https://twitter.com/davkean) confirmed this is a bug.

Comment: [Click](https://mobile.twitter.com/davkean/status/655067698511024128).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's [David Kean](https://twitter.com/davkean) [confirmed](https://twitter.com/davkean/status/655060734011813888) that this actually is a bug.

Comment: Do you have a link to the precise tweet / issue? Your original comment was from October of last year, so the context is a bit lost here.

Comment: Whilst the tweet may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the tweet here. This is because twitter may be blocked for a few users (in college/industry). Do have a look at [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313037/4099593) for more details.